# Spring REST Docs : Read Spring property from .adoc file

Tags: spring-restdocs

I'm using awesome Spring REST Docs to generate the documentation of my Spring Data Rest application.
To do so, I include the generated snippets in a *.adoc* file that is then rendered in HTML (exactly as explained in Spring REST Docs documentation).

My question : is that possible, from the *.adoc* file, to read a Spring property (e.g. defined in *application.properties*) ?

Thank you :)

Comment: It isn't possible out of the box, but Asciidoctor is very extensible so I'm pretty sure you could write some code to do so. What's your use case?

Comment: Also, what build system are you using? I think you could do it quite easily with Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

@Andy Wilkinson : many thanks to your quick answer !

Indeed, it is possible to do it with Gradle. I didn't realize, but I was already "injecting" a property to the .adoc file with the default *asciidoctor* task, as described in the Spring REST Docs documentation.

To add a custom property (*build.gradle*) :

```
ext {
    myProperty='here my custom property'
}

asciidoctor {
    ...
    attributes 'my-property': myProperty
}
```

*my-property* can now be used in .adoc file.

Add to this and to provide a solution to the base question, here is how you can use a Gradle property in the Spring properties file.

In *build.gradle* :

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('**/*.properties') { expand([
            myProperty: myProperty
    ])}
}
```

In *application.properties* :

```
api.myProperty=${myProperty}
```

The property *myProperty* can now be defined once in Gradle build file and then used both in Spring properties and asciidoctor documentation.